# How to make AngularJS components play nice with Bootstrap style?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to compartmentalise a large wedge of code.

I want to create an [angularjs component](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) for a piece of data that is to be displayed in a [bootstrap panel](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels). These panels will be expandable/collapsible.

Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/b3QA39bLB3m0OLtJgl5G?p=preview)

Script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])

.controller('kittenController', function () {
  const $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.click = function () {
    console.log(`You clicked on ${$ctrl.kitten}!`);
  };
})

.component('kittenPanel', {
  templateUrl: 'kitten-panel.template',
  controller: 'kittenController',
  bindings: {
    kitten: '='
  }
});
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.3" data-semver="1.5.3" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap.js@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-init="kittens=[{name: 'Brian', colour: 'Black'}, {name: 'Penny', colour: 'White'},{name: 'Stephanie', colour:'Tortoiseshell'}]">

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="kitten-panel.template">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">{{$ctrl.kitten.name}}</div>
        <div class="panel-body">{{$ctrl.kitten.colour}}</div>
      </div>
    </script>

    <div class="panel-group">
        <kitten-panel kitten="k" ng-repeat="k in kittens"></kitten-panel>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-group">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Heading 1</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Heading 2</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Heading 3</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Content 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

You can see that each panel is butted up against the last because of the way Bootstrap's CSS works.

The second panel group shows what I'd expect to see, with a small gap between each panel in the group.

I need to eliminate the component element that's inserted by angular. But components don't support insertion by attribute.

I'm aware that UI Bootstrap has accordion, but I wanted to get a general solution for how to manage things like this, where angular inserts elements that might break bootstrap.

Any ideas?

Angularjs 1.5.3, Bootstrap 3.3.6

Comment: Why are you using these .panel-group > div > kitten-panel layout? Why not use panel-group>panel ? just put the repeat on the .panel div and get the desired bootstrap structure

Comment: @mikepa88 I updated the example. It doesn't change the outcome because <kitten-panel> is still between .panel-group and .panel.

Answer (score 0):

This is the bootstrap css that puts the margin:

```
.panel-group .panel+.panel{
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

So you need a .panel inside a .panel-group, that comes after another .panel.
In other words, the .panel elements must be on the same level. If you encapsulate them in other elements, this css rule doesn't apply.

```
<div class="panel-group">
       <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="k in kittens">
            <div class="panel-heading">{{k.name}}</div>
            <div class="panel-body">{{k.colour}}</div>
       </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
to use template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="kitten-panel.template">
    <div class="panel-heading">{{$ctrl.kitten.name}}</div>
    <div class="panel-body">{{$ctrl.kitten.colour}}</div>
</script>

<div class="panel-group">    
  <div kitten-panel kitten="k" ng-repeat="k in kittens" class="panel panel-default"></div>
</div>
```

And using directive instead of component as it can use attribute match instead of only element for kitten-panel

Comment: Yep, that's how to do it inline, as it were. I need the componentised version.

Comment: can you put the ng-repeat inisde the template instead of outside? then you have the panels at the same level and the additional element between them and the panel-group, which shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I could do, but then I'd be writing a component for a group of items, which is not quite what I want.

Comment: And getting <div class="panel panel-default"> out of the template and using kitten-panel as a directive so you can reference it as attribute in the .panel div ? thus not creating an additional tag, as the directive and ng-repeat use both the .panel div